# Datepicker "flickering" on window.resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker, window-resize

I have a datepicker inside a jquery dialog window. For some reason I have to close and reopen the datepicker on window.resize. What I have tried so far:

```
$(window).resize(function () {

    if ($("#myDialog").is(":visible")) {
        $("#myDialog").dialog({
            position: {
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: window
            }
        });

        var field = $("#myDialog").find("input.hasDatepicker");
        field.datepicker('hide');
        field.datepicker('show');
    }

});
```

Unfortunatly with this code the datepicker is "flickering" a few times after the resize as a result. How can I avoid this?

PS:
For better visability I also add the original [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/kd7x9zLf/) here, where you can see the problem by reducing the result window:

```js
var dialog = $("#dates").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 'auto',
  modal: true,
  position: {
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: window
  },  
  resizable: false
});


$(function() {
  $("#openDialog").on("click", function() {
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });

  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});


$(window).resize(function() {
  var field = $(document.activeElement);
  if (field.is('.hasDatepicker')) {
    field.datepicker('hide').datepicker('show');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button id="openDialog">
  Click to open Dialog
</button>

<div id="dates" class="hidden">
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date1" />
</div>
```

Comment: That's because for every pixel the windows is resized by you hide then show the datepicker control. I don't know why you feel the need to do this, presumably for positioning purposes. In that case it would make far more sense to just hide the control when resizing starts and simply leave it closed. The user can open it again if required.

Comment: yeah, it's for positioning reasons, exactly. My problem is that the datepicker does not stay connected with the input field once the virtual keyboard slides up on mobile screens. I hoped that this could be a solution. As the keyboard only comes up when you focus the input field it makes no sense to hide the datepicker at all and let the user try to reopen it

Comment: Is it possible to do the hide() and show() only ONCE after a resize?